# Python Try to package my main.py with modules but always same error : ModulenotfoundError

Tags: python, installation, exe, cx-freeze

I try to package all my script.

```
main.py
sample
   src
      file1.py
      file2.py
      util
          file3.py
          file4.py
```

In my main.py, I importe package src and util.

Main.py :

```
from src import *
from util import *
```

setup.py :

```
setup(
    name ="script",
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = "script",
    executables = [Executable("main.py")],
    packages=['sample.src', 'sample.src.util']
)
```

When I run `python setup.py build`I have a directory build with `main.exe` 
but when I run it I always have same error :

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and you have two issues.

1) Add **init**.py files to mark you directories as python modules. 
Like this

[image]

And change your imports to in main.py to that:

```
from sample.src import *
from sample.src.util import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("yeah")
```

Test:

[image]

Comment: thanks your answer ! I have the same error at the end... I have this error too : ? `sample.src.util. imported from main__main__
? sample.src. imported from main__main__
? sample.src.util. imported from main__main__

This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.`

Comment: Ok. Since I could only reproduce the fist error, I dont know whats the Problem. Sorry